# How To Calculate angle between 2 lines at intersection

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to calculate agnle between 2 lines at intersection point.

Please see following image. Here Red line is crossing Green line how can i calculate that angle.?

[image]

Comment: elementary school math?

Comment: Have you even tried *anything*? We´re not here to do your job - which is *search, think and try*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the direction vectors of both lines and normalize them:

```
d := (x2 - x1, y2 - y2)
length = sqrt(d.x^2 + d.y^2)
d := (d.x / length, d.y / length)
```

Then, you have multiple options to calculate the angle. One simple way is to use the dot product:

```
dot = dRed.x * dGreen.x + dRed.y * dGreen.y
angle = arc cos(dot)
```

If you also want to reconstruct angles greater than 180° (you will need correct line orientations then), you need the cross product:

```
cross = dRed.x * dGreen.y - dRed.y * dGreen.x
angle = atan2(cross, dot)
```

Comment: thankyou Sir. i got it except d how to calculate that?

Comment: See the very first code snippet. It is a two-component vector.

Comment: sir i am not getting idea from d:(x2-x1,y2-y1) does it mean
d=(x2-x1) - (y2-y1)?

Comment: No, those are the two components. `d.x = x2 - x1; d.y = y2 - y1`.

Comment: just one last question is the output in radians or degree?

Comment: That depends on the arc cos or atan2 function. They usually output radians.

Answer (score 0):

For functions:

- f(x) = fa * x + fb
- g(x) = ga * x + gb

the angle of intersection (in radians) is:

> PI - [
> arctan(ga) + (PI - arctan(fa))
> ]

or if you have a point of intersection *P*:

> arctan( | f(0) - Py | / Px ) +
> arctan( | g(0) - Py | / Px )

or if you additionally have zero-points (D1 and D2) of functions (so that f(D1) = 0 and g(D2) = 0):

> arctan( | D1 - Px | / Py ) +
> arctan( | D2 - Px | / Py )

**HOW IT WORKS?**

- for a function `f(x) = ax + b`, `a` is tangent of angle between the line and X-axis
- so to get this angle we use *arctan(a)*
- we do the same for other function
- we have 2 angles, let's name them **A** and **B**
- two lines along with X-axis render a triangle (*ABC*)
- angle *AB* equals **A**
- angle *CB* equals *PI - **B*** (angle on "other side" of a line, because **B** is beyond the triangle and we need its counterpart within the triangle)
- sum of triangle angles equals *180°*, or in radians *PI*
- angle *AC = 180° - (AB + CB)*
- thus we get third angle of the triangle, but as intersection angle lays beyond the triangle, we subtract this angle from *180°* (half a circle)

to convert it to degress:

> deg = (180/PI) * rad

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the point of intersection of two lines (if you know the equation of the two lines). Using that point of intersection you can find another point on one of the lines and get the projection of one of the lines onto another. This projection will give you the angle between the two lines.

Also if you know the equation of one of the lines and a point on another line, you can still use this method to find out the angle between the two lines.

Comment: i have cordinates of both lines 
red (x1,y1) - (x2,y2)
green (x1,y1) - (x2,y2)